# Button Background Bug

Tags: html, css, button

I decided that the best way to learn Front End is by starting with Landing Pages in HTML & CSS.

I am trying to figure out how to increase the background that is behind the font of the button so it doesn't looks so crowded. Any typs?

This is the code I have so far:

```css
.btns{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #d8d8d8;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #191919;
  padding: 12px 20 px;
  float: left;
  border:0;
  border-radius:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

**Image for reference**

[image]

Comment: `padding: 12px 20px;` without space

Answer (score 2):

`padding: 12px 20px` should do the job.

You made a small typo in there ;)

```css
.btns{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #191919;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    float: left;
    border:0;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btns">Hello</button>
```